# Python word checker

Tags: python

```
emp = []

def run(first, second):
     front_index = 0
     back_index = 0
     if len(first) > len(second):
         front = second
         back = first
         num = first_bigger_than_second(front, back)
         return num
     elif len(first) < len(second):
         front = first
         back = second
         break
     else:
         front = second
         back = first
         break

def first_bigger_than_second(first, back):
    first_index = 0
    back_index = 0
    print(len(first))
    print(len(back))
    while first_index < len(first) and back_index < len(back):
        if first[first_index] == back[back_index] and back_index == len(back):
            print("first", first)
            print("first_index", first_index)
            print("first[first_index]", first[first_index])
            print("back", back)
            print("back_index", back_index)
            print("back[back_index]", back[back_index])
            emp.append(back[back_index])
            first_index += 1
            back_index = 0
            print(1)
        elif first[first_index] == back[back_index]:
            print("first", first)
            print("first_index", first_index)
            print("first[first_index]", first[first_index])
            print("back", back)
            print("back_index", back_index)
            print("back[back_index]", back[back_index])
            emp.append(back[back_index])
            back_index += 1
            print(2)
        elif back_index == len(back) - 1:
            print("first", first)
            print("first_index", first_index)
            print("first[first_index]", first[first_index])
            print("back", back)
            print("back_index", back_index)
            print("back[back_index]", back[back_index])
            first_index += 1
            back_index = 0
            print(3)
        else:
            print("first", first)
            print("first_index", first_index)
            print("first[first_index]", first[first_index])
            print("back", back)
            print("back_index", back_index)
            print("back[back_index]", back[back_index])
            back_index += 1
            print(4)

num1 = 0plm1qaz
num2 = 1qaz0pl
run(num1, num2)
print(emp)
"""
```

All the `print` functions are used to trace with if loop is been executed

The problem is when I print the `emp`, the output is `["1", "q", "a", "z"]` expected output is: `["1", "q", "a", "z", "0", "p", "l"]`.

The code compares two word user inputs and returns the same word. Example: When you input `"2aba"` and "`2ac"` , it will give a result as `["2", "a", "a"]` since the code is work like the `"2"` from the `"2aba"` compare  with `"2ac"` and the `"a"` from the `"2aba"` is compared again with `"2ac"` and `"b"` from the `"2aba"` is compared with `"2ac"` and `"a"` from the `"2aba"` compare with `"2ac"`

Answer (score 1):

`break` in your `run()`  raises `SyntaxError` as there is no loop. After removing it, your code can run but it is not giving you expected result.

When `first_index = 3 (z in num2)`, `back_index = 7 (z in num1)`, the second elif statement runs, `back_index + 1 = 8 == len(num1)`, while loop break and you get the result `["1", "q", "a", "z"]`. Although you put the first and third if statement to reset the back_index, the first one never run as the while loop already break and the third one will not run as the second one runs.

We can use `in` to check if a character of a word exist in another word.

```
def same_chars(first,second):
    # use the shorter one as first
    if len(first) > len(second):
        first, second = second, first
    emp = [chars for chars in first if chars in second]
    return emp

num1 = "0plm1qaz"
num2 = "1qaz0pl"
print(same_chars(num1, num2))
```

Output:

```
['1', 'q', 'a', 'z', '0', 'p', 'l']
```